# Where can I find the Pictures / Music / Downloads folder icons?

Tags: icons, directory, customization

First of all, I know this question seems very common. I know the `/usr/share/icons/Humanity/places` folder. So this is not exactly about it.

On a fresh install, when you open Nautilus, you see your Home folder. It has several default folders with special icons, such as Downloads, Music, Pictures, etc. They are also bookmarked, so that you can see them on the sidebar. Actually two different icons are displayed : in the main panel, this is the `places/64/folder-music.svg` that is displayed. In the sidebar, this is `places/16/folder-music.svg`

I deleted this Music folder. I created it again, and customized the icon using `/usr/share/icons/Humanity/places/64/folder-music.svg` But in the sidebar, the icon is a resized version of this one, not the `16` version !

How can I recreate the original behaviour?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Finally, I figured it out by myself (or, to be honest, with help from [an ArchLinux forum](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=134641)).
So, in the sidebar, this special folders are not under "Bookmarks" but under "Computer". To include custom folders in this list, you have to edit `~/.config/user-dirs.dirs`.

Here's the content of mine :

```
# This file is written by xdg-user-dirs-update
# If you want to change or add directories, just edit the line you're
# interested in. All local changes will be retained on the next run
# Format is XDG_xxx_DIR="$HOME/yyy", where yyy is a shell-escaped
# homedir-relative path, or XDG_xxx_DIR="/yyy", where /yyy is an
# absolute path. No other format is supported.
# 
XDG_DESKTOP_DIR="$HOME/Bureau"
XDG_DOWNLOAD_DIR="$HOME/Téléchargements"
XDG_TEMPLATES_DIR="$HOME/Modèles"
XDG_PUBLICSHARE_DIR="$HOME/Public"
XDG_DOCUMENTS_DIR="$HOME/Documents"
XDG_MUSIC_DIR="$HOME/Musique"
XDG_PICTURES_DIR="$HOME/Images"
XDG_VIDEOS_DIR="$HOME/Vidéos"
```

It happens that the line concerning music had become `XDG_MUSIC_DIR="$HOME/` after I had deleted the Music folder.

Once you have filled this file appropriately, most of work is done. But if you have also customized your icons by changing it to `usr/share/icons/whatever` you may also want to reset the icon to default by right-clicking on the folder icon, then going to Properties, clicking on the icon and pressing "reset" at the bottom of the window.

Comment: Thanks!! Was wondering where they stored this config information.