# Deleted Pictures folder - how do I get it back?

Tags: directory, home-directory

I let my little brother use my computer and now the (official) `Pictures` folder isn't there anymore.

How do I restore it? I already made a folder named `pictures` but it isn't the same since it has no special folder icon.

Comment: Have a look the answer of this Question. https://askubuntu.com/questions/171263/where-can-i-find-the-pictures-music-downloads-folder-icons It should help

Comment: Refer to [this question,](http://askubuntu.com/questions/150671/accidentally-deleted-a-folder) and in the future you may want to password protect your computer ;-)

Comment: Capital p... Not pictures